# HTML {% %} tags?

Tags: html, django

I was watching a video coding html, and I saw in the video they used a bit of code that looked like this:

> `<body>
>
>   {% block %}
>
>   {% endblock %}
>
>   </body>`

Is this some form of commenting in html? I think the coder they were using was Espresso for Mac. I've just never seen it.
The video is here:
http://vimeo.com/7405114, at about 5 minutes in, toward the very end.

Answer (score 5):

They are Django template blocks:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 2):

Those are a [Django block tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block). They're used in template inheritance to define a block of text in a template that can be replaced in children templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely in the video it says that they are blocks for the [Django template system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/).

They contain code in the [Django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#topics-templates).

Answer (score 0):

Comments in HTML are created by <!-- and -->. The {% ... %} is propably a placeholder which gets replaced later.